# Rails tagging and tag list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, tagging

I saw alot of good tagging plugins but are these plugins really what I want?

I want to:
- Tag products, users and news
- Search by tags
- List all tags like SELECT DISTINCT tag (for a autocomplete tag list and button tags like here on stackoverflow).

I'm thinking of a separated model Tag. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The two most popular plugins (according to [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_tagging.html)) both use two separate models to realize tagging of arbitrary classes. Since your classes seem to be known beforehand, you might get away with using just one. Here are the proper URLs to both plugins for reference:

- [acts-as-taggable-on](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)
- [is_taggable](http://github.com/jamesgolick/is_taggable)

Comment: Be careful about giving ruby toolbox too much weight in your decision making.  It does give you rough stats on usage via github data but it will also skew towards older plugins over newer better plugins.

Comment: But these plugins do not seem to be addressing the problem of - SELECT DISTINCT tags list (for autocomplete)